# turning a lapply list into a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply, glm

i'm using the following code to run log regressions subbing the "i" for a bunch of pre-specified vars.

```
fits <- lapply(vars, function(x) {glm(substitute(outcome ~ staticPredictor + i, 
        list(i = as.name(x))), family=binomial, data = data)})
```

I'm able to print out lists w/ coefficients and p-values, but am looking to transform these lists into a dataframe with the following headings:

> [modelname] [staticPredictor coefficient] [i coefficient]
> [staticPredictor p-value] [i p-value].

this is my code for the lists i am currently able to populate

```
coeffs <- lapply(fits, coefficients) 
pvals <- sapply(fits, function(f) summary(f)$coefficients[,4])
```

thank you!!!!

Comment: Please provide a complete example as per the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `tidy` from `broom`

```
library(purrr)
library(broom)
map_dfr(fits, tidy)
```